# How to completely disable JDBC Connection Pooling in Spring / Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, database-connection

I'm using a Spring Data Source bean to configure a JDBC connection.

What's the easiest way to have this return a bare, unpooled / unmanaged JDBC connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource` this class is a very simple implementation of `javax.sql.DataSource` and doesn't implement connection pooling, instead it always returns a new connection.

You can find source code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/SimpleDriverDataSource.java)