# How do I use disable connection pooling in Spring boot app?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I create a datasource like this in my Application.java:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

But it returns a managed datasource with pooling. due to the particular type of db I am working with, I want to disable the pooling.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Is the pool the issue or is multiple connections the issue? You can configure it to create a pool with 1 connection.

Comment: sorry, keeping one connection is a problem. I need a new fresh connection each time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completely disable Connection Pooling in Spring / Tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665860/how-to-completely-disable-connection-pooling-in-spring-tomcat)

Comment: okay, but how would I change my configuration to use SimpleDriverDataSource ?

Comment: Lots of examples here. http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DataSourceBuilder` has a method called `type(Class)` where you can specify the class which you want to use as DataSource implementation. So in your case it can look like this:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(SimpleDriverDataSource.class).build();
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I've an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Driver must not be null
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]. I set driverName on DataSourceBuilder. Some ideas? Thanks

Comment: The DataSourceBuilder method doesn't work as the default constructor for SimpleDriverDataSource does not instantiate a driver. Just use the constructors/setters of SimpleDriverDataSource and specify the driver class like `org.postgresql.Driver.class` for postgresql, etc.

Comment: @dunni Neither SimpleDriverDataSource nor DriverManagerDataSource classes provide close method. Does this mean we don't need to close the connection ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution I use, adapted it from the SpringBoot 2.5 autoconfiguration of Liquibase, whose case was discussed here : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24944
(code reference : https://github.com/wilkinsona/spring-boot/blob/gh-24944/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java)

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("datasource")
public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
    String url = dataSourceProperties.determineUrl();
    String user = dataSourceProperties.determineUsername();
    String password = dataSourceProperties.determinePassword();
    String driverClassName = DatabaseDriver.fromJdbcUrl(url).getDriverClassName();    
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(SimpleDriverDataSource.class).url(url).username(user)
        .password(password).driverClassName(driverClassName).build();
}
```