# Create new java.sql.Connection for every new request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Currently, in my spring boot application has the capability to create connection object based on the DataSource given. In my manager layer, I have annotated with @Transactional. I need to have a new connection when entering methods in manager, even though we have an existing connection.

Comment: Generally speaking that would be a bad idea. Setting up a connection is an expensive operation. It is far more efficient to reuse a connection from the pool. Is there any special requirement why you can't reuse a connection?

Comment: Yes, it looks like a special requirement @fhossfel, we are using a temporary tables on the connection

Comment: Why don't you clean the temporary tables on commit? At least with Oracle that is the default.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not a good idea, disabling connection pooling should always return a new connection. [How to completely disable Connection Pooling in Spring / Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665860/how-to-completely-disable-connection-pooling-in-spring-tomcat)

- **NOTE: This class is not an actual connection pool; it does not actually
  pool Connections.** It just serves as simple replacement for a full-blown
  connection pool, implementing the same standard interface, but creating new
  Connections on every call.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/SimpleDriverDataSource.java

Answer (score 0):

I would not create new connections every time you call any sort of transactional method.  This is expensive and very error-prone.  You should be defining your data sources and then choosing which one you want to use.

Also, see [Spring Boot Configure and Use Two DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources)